# Saving spark dataset to an existing csv file

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to save the contents of dataset to csv using

```
df.coalesce(1)
  .write()
  .format("csv")
  .mode("append")
  .save(PATH+"/trial.csv");
```

My aim is to keep appending the results of dataset to trial.csv file. However, it creates a folder called trial.csv and creates csv inside of that. When I run it again, it creates another csv file inside the trail.csv folder. But I just want it to keep appending to one csv file, which I unable to do.

I know we can do some script from outside of code(program) and do it, but can we achieve it from inside our code? I am using Java.

Answer (score 1):

Appending to an existing file its something hard to do for a distributed, multi-thread application, it will turn something parallelised into a sequential task. The way that is usually achieved, is to persist per thread or task in spark, a single file in the specified path, and this path will be a folder containing all the files. To read them, you can read the complete folder.

If your data is not big, and you really need a single file, try with `repartition` method to 1, this will make a single task to write the new data, but it will never append the data to previous files.

You have to be careful, but you can do something like this:

```
df.union(spark.read(PATH+"/trial.csv"))
  .coalesce(1)
  .write
  .format("csv")
  .mode("append")
  .save(PATH+"/trial_auxiliar.csv")
```

Then move it to the previous folder, with spark or a move command of Hadoop. Never write and read in the same job to the same folder, and keep in mind that this won't guarantee the data order.

Comment: I am doing coalesce for that only, since I want a single file and my data is also small. So, one csv gets generated per run, but I want to have it in a single file for multiple runs.

Comment: directly with spark it's impossible, use a script to contact files at the end of the job

Comment: I was also thinking the same. But just wanted to check if there is any chance to do from inside the program. Thanks

Comment: Or,  read the previous data, union it with the new one, and write in a auxiliary place